New faculty position – expectation to change research direction
I am mainly looking for advice, perspectives and thoughts from other colleagues.
For many years I have undertaken self-directed research as a Senior Researcher in the field of mental health. It has led to many successes including academic outputs and research income. This success paid off when I was recently awarded a permanent academic position but in a new Faculty.
Since joining this new Faculty it has become clear that the Head is not keen on me continuing my own research portfolio (for which I believed I was hired for), but instead directing me to undertake work that is aligned to their own interests which are a significant departure from my own (no reference to this in the job listing). Time allocated to my own interests (and associated projects) has been removed, and it is expected I do this in my “own time”. I have done this, but kept the Head informed, but they have never asked a question or shown any interest.
It is also unusual, as no academic objectives were set: It was agreed when I joined I could continue some work in my primary area of interest but also support the wider Faculty. I have attempted to discuss this with the Head, but they appear to say one thing in the meetings, then do the opposite afterwards.
I am keen to get different perspectives, advice or guidance on how best to handle this situation. Or if this is normal?

How permanent is permanent? In other words, what power does the new Head have over your employment? Have you considered discussing with the Dean?

You are a tenure track faculty at a respectable university and are being told what to research by your department head? Sorry but this seems very fishy to me, I think there are some important details you’re not communicating. If you want to get a good quality answer, can you clarify: 1. What country is this in? (Or what part of the world if you are concerned about anonymity.) 2. Is this a university or some other kind of research institution? 3. Any other details you can share about the nature of your position? “Permanent academic position” is unhelpfully vague.

One of the main features of Academic Freedom is the ability and expectation that one sets one's own research direction, so yes, this is unusual. But probably not unprecedented. There are two factors here.
First is that the department/faculty is new and they might generally want to become known for a certain research direction. But even if that is the case, it should have been made very clear to you in the application process.
The other factor is the Head, himself, who may be over-controlling rather than collegial. That is unfortunate and you have decisions to make as to whether you can accept it. I'd suggest you keep your eyes open for other opportunities, actually.
Academic Freedom applies, or should, to even low level faculty, such as newly hired Assistant Professors and the equivalent. Actually it should apply even to part-time faculty. This distinguishes academia from the industrial world where you are expected to comply with the demands of management.
Note that I'm assuming that you are in a university situation and not a focused research laboratory, which might operate more like the industrial world in expectations. But, even there, the expectations should have been made clear as part of the application process. You do say "faculty position", of course.

One comment -- academic customs differ greatly by subject, by country, by institution type, and many other factors. So take any advice you get from strangers on the internet (including mine!) with a grain of salt.
I would see if your university has a "faculty ombuds" or similar position -- and, if so, meet with this person. Generally speaking, an ombuds (or ombudsman) is someone who will listen to faculty concerns, give advice, and maintain confidentiality. They will not intervene, but they will give you the "lay of the land" and let you know how typical your head's demands are for your institution -- and what the consequences might be if you decide to pursue your own research interests instead.
At my university, department heads rotate fairly frequently, and hold limited power. Consider that when you go up for tenure, there might be a new department head who does not share the old head's priorities. Overall, where I work, your head's demands would be considered ridiculous.
Tread carefully, seek advice from as many people at your institution as possible, don't do anything rash. My initial thought -- knowing nothing of your individual situation -- is that you should seek a way of continuing your own research program, while perhaps contributing a bit to your head's -- but, above all, please seek advice more reliable than what this anonymous stranger on the internet can give.

This is a good answer. Get a picture of how things work at your place, who wields the power, etc. Even if formally the Head has no power to tell you what to do, they can make one's life miserable. It is a red flag that nothing of the change to research direction was mentioned in the interview. That is really not in anyone's interest in the end. Find out what really counts. Your agreement on hiring, or the Head's opinion.

It depends on the situation. As a tenure tracked professor, I would not expect it. In Germany there are "akademische Räte", who have permanent positions and are expected to work with their professor. They have some minor freedoms but it is limited. When the professor changes, they have to adjust to completely new direction of research.
So there is a spectrum. I don't know how this applies to mental health and the country you are living.
